# Installing Python 2.4 on CentOS 8 fails with segmentation fault

Tags: python, centos8

I am having problems installing Python 2.4.6 on CentOS 8.
I need the old Python 2.4.6 because I have some apps running which require Python 2.4.

I downloaded the Python 2.4.6.tgz package, extracted it and run "./configure" which works.
When I try to run "make", I see a lot of warnings and at the end the following error message is shown:

```
gcc -pthread  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python \
        Modules/python.o \
        libpython2.4.a -lpthread -ldl  -lutil   -lm  
libpython2.4.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tmpnam':
/usr/local/src/Python-2.4.6/./Modules/posixmodule.c:6240: warning: the use of `tmpnam_r' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
libpython2.4.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tempnam':
/usr/local/src/Python-2.4.6/./Modules/posixmodule.c:6195: warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
case $MAKEFLAGS in \
*-s*)  CC='gcc -pthread' LDSHARED='gcc -pthread -shared' OPT='-DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes' ./python -E ./setup.py -q build;; \
*)  CC='gcc -pthread' LDSHARED='gcc -pthread -shared' OPT='-DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes' ./python -E ./setup.py build;; \
esac
/bin/sh: line 1:  5296 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) CC='gcc -pthread' LDSHARED='gcc -pthread -shared' OPT='-DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes' ./python -E ./setup.py build
make: *** [Makefile:342: sharedmods] Error 139
```

Any idea, what might be wrong here? If required, I can post the whole output after I run "make" (which is quite long).
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go a different route than installing Python 2.4 on your OS. That thing is ancient, it can only bring security issues.

So if your apps don't work with even Python 2.7, perhaps you have better luck with running Python 2.4 in a Docker. See e.g. https://github.com/pantuza/docker-python-2.4.3 for a docker image with Python 2.4 and https://www.docker.com/get-started for an introduction on docker.

And probably the next step should be porting those apps to Python 3, such that you can get rid of that ancient Python version for good.